# Responsive size screen flutter: How to set base_width?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, screen-size

Image of the app and code

[image: 1]

i'm trying to do a responsive for screen size flutter app, but the screen-size overflows.

I downloaded the code from function 12 from a figma design and i've made some changes but i don't know how to get the base width depending on the device so the fem is calculated correctly. Thank you very much.

```
class _ScheduleState extends State<Schedule> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double baseWidth = 380;
    double fem = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / baseWidth;
    double ffem = fem * 0.97;
```

Answer (score 2):

Flutter automatically takes care of the responsive part

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

This returns full width of the screen. You will get exact value for all devices. No need to set a base width here.

If you need to add your custom width you could set a percentage of the available width based on the value you get from
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.80
```

This will return 80% of the available width

There are several ways to manage text overflow in Flutter, suggest you to take a look in the [Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html).

```
Text(
  'Hello, $_name! How are you?',
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Explore other options of TextOverflow here
  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
)
```

A bit off context, I saw your attached image.
I suggest warp your Container with body and Scaffold when you are creating a page to remove the yellow lines.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
    )
  }
```